# How to record audio of the live virtual piano player I created in a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, recording

I made an online piano player using html and javascript. Now I want to add a function for recording/pausing/stopping and playing the live sound produced by the virtual piano. How to set the source of the sound as the sound produced by each key of piano and how to implement the recording thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question as it stands is too broad to be easily answered. Please include examples of the code you have already tried in order to narrow the scope. You might also want to check out the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for guidance.

Comment: Hi Bryan... This is the link of the thing I made: www.piano-rainbow.appspot.com and I want to add the recording feature to it. Whatever an user plays he or she can record it.

Comment: Arijit, the link does provide some needed context, but your question still needs more details in order to be answerable. The SO community will be much more able to assist if you edit your question and add the code you've tried and include a more targeted and specific question about the parts that aren't working.